# Does not read the entire input stream in android

Tags: android

I am trying to read a response from a server and transform it from InputStream to String but something goes wrong and i cannot see right now why.

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();
FileOutputStream folder = new FileOutputStream(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/test.xml");
try {
byte[] buf = new byte[1048576];
int current = 0;
int newCurrent = 0;
while ((current = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
    newCurrent = newCurrent + current;
    folder.write(buf, 0, current);
}
System.out.println("returned folder" + folder);
folder.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("error on reading input: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

This is the error:

```
    error on reading input: Socket closed
```

This is the error I get and another problem that i don't understand is why it does not read the entire content from InputStream(maybe because it's all in one line?).
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need to read entire stream in one shot and put it in a byte array, in fact you read it in parts through while loop and put the contents in file stream gradually:

```
int count;
byte[] filebytes = new byte[1024];
while((count = is.read(filebytes)) != -1){
   folder.write(filebytes, 0, count);   //writing buffer into file
}
in.close();
folder.flush();
folder.close();
```

Comment: now it works, it was my fault. I reduced the buffer size to 1024 and it worked. I did not understand the socket error either and why I received it. thx

Answer (score 0):

According to stacktrace your crash happens in `readLine()` while your code uses is.`read(buf)`.

DO these match together?